# Retrieve information SELECET from tables

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve information, specifically the names and the total number of unique activities of an athelete (which i've renamed "sports Variety". I want to rank first the athlete who does more activities, but I'm not sure how to approach this.

[image: Table 1]
[image: Table 2]

I also know I should use DISTINCT somewhere, but not sure where to put it. I also don't know how to sort by unique/most activities.

```
SELECT athlete.name, COUNT(athlete.name) AS 'Sports Variety' FROM athlete 
INNER JOIN athlete ON athlete.id = training_session.activity GROUP BY 
training_session.activity HAVING COUNT(athlete) > 0
```

I expect it to be 6 rows to be returned.

Comment: your data sample is not clear  ...  instead of image you should add  a proper data sample as tabular text and the expected  result

Comment: You could start by including your sample data and expected output as text which we can use rather than images which we cannot. AND what version of mysql are you on?

Comment: 'I expect it to be 6 rows to be returned.' - what 6 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have two table  one name athlete with athlete name  and one name training_session for the activities related  to each athletes

```
SELECT athlete.name, COUNT(*) AS 'Sports Variety' 
FROM athlete 
INNER JOIN training_session ON athlete.id = training_session.athlete_id 
GROUP BY athlete.name
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the athlete having the most activities, you could try a `LIMIT` query:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.name,
    COUNT(*) AS num_activities
FROM athlete a
INNER JOIN training_session ts
    ON a.id = ts.athelete_id
GROUP BY
    a.id,
    a.name
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

I see a handful of syntax problems with your current query, such as the second table name is the same as the first (not what you want here).  Note that my query doesn't handle the possibility that two or more athletes might happen to have the same amount of activity.  To resolve that, we could either find something else to rank, or restructure the query.

Comment: Thank you, I know at least now what i need to use :)